# C++ SFML compile error + install

Tags: c++, sfml

Hey i keep getting this error when compiling sfml code.

```
    root@ubuntu:/home/bugtraq# g++ ttt.o -L /home/me/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libudev.so.1, needed by /home/me/lib/libsfml-graphics.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_action@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_receive_device@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_devnode@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_enable_receiving@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_get_fd@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `__cpu_model@GCC_4.8.0'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_property_value@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_syspath@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_new_from_netlink@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath@LIBUDEV_183'
/home/me/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype@LIBUDEV_183'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code im using is the one from SFML official webpage. 
I don't no if i installed it correctly but i made a folder called
/home/me/ 
And untared SFML4 and mv it into /home/me/SFML
When i do g++ -C ttt.cpp it works but the final part.

g++ ttt.o -L /home/me/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

Gives me the error code any help?

Comment: Did you install libudev?

Comment: Yes i did. Im not sure what is going on. i can get SFML 1.6 to work but when i manually install SMFL2.0+ it doesn't seem to work